# deactivate speech recognition for ervery command except for activate speech recognition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

so I have a lot of commands for my voice assistant that I programmed with visual studio (2019) c# System.Speech and now I want to add a command that deactivates the speech recognition until I say activate speech recognition.

I tried looking through the internet but I haven't found anything yet and I don't know a method myself that would be worth trying. Just deactivating every other command seperatly would be way to much effort.

Does anyone know how to do this or has an idea?

Thx for helping, phantomica

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Comment: Sry was gone for a while so didn't check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description,when the shutdown command appears, you want to deactivate
speech recognition for every command except for activate speech recognition.

You can follow the steps below to achieve your requirements:

1. Set a global static variable speechOn, the default value is true.
2. Try to convert each recognized speech into text and store it in a variable. Then use this variable to compare with "speech on" and "speech off".
3. Determine the Boolean value of speechOn through the second step. If false, use return; to end the recognition method. If true, continue the recognition method.

My test code is as follows, it was successfully tested.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleSpeech
{
    class ConsoleSpeechProgram
    {
        static SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
        static bool done = false;
        static bool speechOn = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ss.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                Console.WriteLine("\n(Speaking: I am awake)");
                ss.Speak("I am awake");
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
                sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
                sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sre.SpeechRecognized += sre_SpeechRecognized;
                Choices ch_StartStopCommands = new Choices();
                ch_StartStopCommands.Add("speech on");
                ch_StartStopCommands.Add("speech off");
                ch_StartStopCommands.Add("klatu barada nikto");
                GrammarBuilder gb_StartStop = new GrammarBuilder();
                gb_StartStop.Append(ch_StartStopCommands);
                Grammar g_StartStop = new Grammar(gb_StartStop);
                Choices ch_Numbers = new Choices();
                ch_Numbers.Add("1");
                ch_Numbers.Add("2");
                ch_Numbers.Add("3");
                ch_Numbers.Add("4");
                GrammarBuilder gb_WhatIsXplusY = new GrammarBuilder();
                gb_WhatIsXplusY.Append("What is");
                gb_WhatIsXplusY.Append(ch_Numbers);
                gb_WhatIsXplusY.Append("plus");
                gb_WhatIsXplusY.Append(ch_Numbers);
                Grammar g_WhatIsXplusY = new Grammar(gb_WhatIsXplusY);
                sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g_StartStop);
                sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g_WhatIsXplusY);
                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                while (done == false) {; }
                Console.WriteLine("\nHit <enter> to close shell\n");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } // Main
        static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender,
          SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = e.Result.Text;
            float confidence = e.Result.Confidence;
            Console.WriteLine("\nRecognized: " + txt);
            if (confidence < 0.60) return;
            if (txt.IndexOf("speech on") >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speech is now ON");
                speechOn = true;
            }
            if (txt.IndexOf("speech off") >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speech is now OFF");
                speechOn = false;
            }
            if (speechOn == false) return;
            if (txt.IndexOf("klatu") >= 0 && txt.IndexOf("barada") >= 0)
            {
                ((SpeechRecognitionEngine)sender).RecognizeAsyncCancel();
                done = true;
                Console.WriteLine("(Speaking: Farewell)");
                ss.Speak("Farewell");
            }
            if (txt.IndexOf("What") >= 0 && txt.IndexOf("plus") >= 0)
            {
                string[] words = txt.Split(' ');
                int num1 = int.Parse(words[2]);
                int num2 = int.Parse(words[4]);
                int sum = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine("(Speaking: " + words[2] + " plus " +
                  words[4] + " equals " + sum + ")");
                ss.SpeakAsync(words[2] + " plus " + words[4] +
                  " equals " + sum);
            }
        } // sre_SpeechRecognized
    } // Program
} // ns
```

[image]

[Voice Recognition : Speech Recognition with .NET Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/december/voice-recognition-speech-recognition-with-net-desktop-applications)